# Using Raycast instead of Gaze Pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusgo

I'm new to VR development,I'm using oculus integration so I made a ray line with the line renderer , but now I need to make this line interactive with everything like a gaze pointer (objects,UI, Scrolls..),, I'm testing my project on Oculus Go

[image: screenshot of my project here]

I have tried a lot of tutorials but no one focuses on this point.

Here's my attempt at the code:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward ,out hit,0.8f))
{
    if(hit.collider != null)
    {
        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger)) 
        { 
            go = hit.transform.gameObject;
            go.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This works for objects but not with UI like how a GazePointer works.

Comment: You need use `Physics2D` class to hit the UI elements.

Comment: You can use the [`GraphicRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) which is usually attached to a `Canvas` by default. The question: Do you want it to hit if the line intersects the UI or only if the front end of the line is over the UI?

Comment: You laos could simply add `BoxCollider` to your buttons .. then you wouldn't have to change any code ;)

Comment: @derHugo i need it full interactive with controller line ray like Oculus home view .. i search for the best way to do that

Comment: @shingo `Physics2D` won't help much here since it would project the 3D world into a flat 2D world ... but what if you point over a UI.Button? You don't want to hit it in that case .. which the `Physcis2D.Raycast` would ..

Comment: Checkout maybe [SteamVR Laser Pointer Menus](https://unity3d.college/2017/06/17/steamvr-laser-pointer-menus/) you should be able to adopt the required behaviours to Oculus quite easily ... they use `BoxCollider` as I suggested as well .. and simply made a script that scales the BoxCollider to the correct Button dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also interessted in something like this so I got a bit deeper into the mentioned [SteamVR Laser Pointer Menus](https://unity3d.college/2017/06/17/steamvr-laser-pointer-menus).

The general idea is quite simple:

- On all interactable UI use `BoxCollider`
- Then you can simply stick to `Physics.Raycast`
- If pointing on a UI element additionally fire the according [`EventSystems.ExecuteEvents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.html)

In reality this looks a bit more complex. I created my own script based on the `steamvr_laserpointer.cs` but had to change it a lot in order to cover most of the interactions.

**It is not fully working yet** - while it basicaly already works perfect for 3D objects and simple button interactions I have a little trouble getting the **dragging** to work properly. But I hope this is a good startpoint for everyone trying something similar:

#### LaserPointerController.cs

(Originally based on `steamvr_laserpointer.cs`)

This is attached to your controller GameObject. It will create a child object "LaserHolder" which also has a child "LaserPointer". The "LaserPointer" is basically simply a cube which is scaled so it looks like a laser beam.-

```
#define USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR

using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
#if UNITY_EDITOR && USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class LaserPointerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Inspector

    [Header("Pointer Settings")]
    [Tooltip("Should the LaserPointer origin have an offset to the controller position (in local coordinates)?")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useOffset;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

    [Tooltip("The maximal distance of the laser pointer (in Unity Units)")]
    [SerializeField] private float maxPointerDistance = 5f;

    [Tooltip("Should the laser have a Collider attached?\nUseful for e.g. directly using OnTriggerEnter\n\nNote: This will use Physics.RaycastAll which is less efficient.")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useCollider;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser Collider be a trigger?\nHas to be disabled to e.g. use OnCollisionEnter")]
    [SerializeField] private bool colliderIsTrigger;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser additionally have a RigidBody?\nRequired for some types of collisions.")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useRigidBody;

    [Header("Style Settings")]
    [Tooltip("Should the laser change its Color when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private bool changeColor;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser change its thickness when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private bool changeThickness;
    [Tooltip("Color of the Laser in idle")]
    [SerializeField] private Color idleColor = Color.red;
    [Tooltip("Color of the beam when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private Color pressedColor = Color.green;
    [Tooltip("Thickness of the laser beam")]
    [SerializeField] private float idleThickness = 0.005f;
    [Tooltip("Thickness of the laser beam when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private float pressedThickness = 0.007f;

    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private bool isPressed;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 pointerPosition3D;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 pointerPosition2D;

#if UNITY_EDITOR && USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(LaserPointerController))]
    private class LaserPointerControllerEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty useOffset;
        private SerializedProperty offset;

        private SerializedProperty maxPointerDistance;

        private SerializedProperty useCollider;
        private SerializedProperty colliderIsTrigger;
        private SerializedProperty useRigidBody;

        private SerializedProperty changeColor;
        private SerializedProperty changeThickness;
        private SerializedProperty idleColor;
        private SerializedProperty pressedColor;
        private SerializedProperty idleThickness;
        private SerializedProperty pressedThickness;

        private SerializedProperty _isPressed;
        private SerializedProperty pointerPosition3D;
        private SerializedProperty pointerPosition2D;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            useOffset = serializedObject.FindProperty("useOffset");
            offset = serializedObject.FindProperty("offset");

            maxPointerDistance = serializedObject.FindProperty("maxPointerDistance");
            useCollider = serializedObject.FindProperty("useCollider");
            colliderIsTrigger = serializedObject.FindProperty("colliderIsTrigger");
            useRigidBody = serializedObject.FindProperty("useRigidBody");

            changeColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("changeColor");
            changeThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("changeThickness");
            idleColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("idleColor");
            pressedColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("pressedColor");
            idleThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("idleThickness");
            pressedThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("pressedThickness");

            _isPressed = serializedObject.FindProperty("isPressed");
            pointerPosition3D = serializedObject.FindProperty("pointerPosition3D");
            pointerPosition2D = serializedObject.FindProperty("pointerPosition2D");
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            DrawScriptField();

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useOffset);
            if (useOffset.boolValue)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(offset);
                EditorGUILayout.Space();
            }

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(maxPointerDistance);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useCollider);
            if (useCollider.boolValue)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(colliderIsTrigger);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useRigidBody);
            }
            else
            {
                colliderIsTrigger.boolValue = true;
                useRigidBody.boolValue = false;
            }

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(changeColor);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(changeThickness);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(idleColor);
            if (changeColor.boolValue) EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pressedColor);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(idleThickness);
            if (changeThickness.boolValue) EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pressedThickness);

            if (EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_isPressed);

                EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pointerPosition3D);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pointerPosition2D);
                }
                EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
            }

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        private void DrawScriptField()
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
            {
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((LaserPointerController)target), typeof(LaserPointerController), false);
            }
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }
    }
#endif

    #endregion Inspector


    #region Public Members

    public Vector3 PointerPosition3D
    {
        get { return pointerPosition3D; }
    }

    public Vector2 PointerPosition2D
    {
        get { return pointerPosition2D; }
    }

    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get { return isPressed; }
    }

    public Transform CurrentlyHoveredTransform
    {
        get { return _currentlyHovered; }
    }

    #endregion Public Members


    #region Private Members

    private Transform _holder;
    private Transform _laser;
    private Transform _currentlyHovered;
    private Material _laserMaterial;

    private PointerEventData _pointerEventData;
    private Vector2 _lastPointerPosition;
    private bool _isDragging;
    private bool _lastPressed;
    private Camera _camera;

    #endregion Private Members


    #region MonoBehaviour Messages
    private void Awake()
    {
        _holder = new GameObject("LaserHolder").transform;
        _holder.parent = transform;
        _holder.localScale = Vector3.one;
        _holder.localPosition = useOffset ? offset : Vector3.zero;
        _holder.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        _laser = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform;
        var collider = _laser.GetComponent<Collider>();

        if (!useCollider)
        {
            Destroy(_laser.GetComponent<Collider>());
        }
        else
        {
            collider.isTrigger = colliderIsTrigger;
        }

        if (useRigidBody)
        {
            var rigidBody = _laser.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidBody.useGravity = false;
            rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
        }

        _laser.name = "LaserPointer";
        _laser.transform.parent = _holder;
        _laser.transform.localScale = new Vector3(idleThickness, idleThickness, maxPointerDistance);
        _laser.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, maxPointerDistance / 2f);
        _laser.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        _laserMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color")) { color = idleColor };
        _laser.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = _laserMaterial;

        _camera = Camera.main;

        _pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current)
        {
            // most Unity comonents e.g. the ScrollRect expect this to be Left
            // otherwise they ignore pointer input
            button = PointerEventData.InputButton.Left
        };
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _holder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _holder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        //TODO uncomment this in order to get the isPressed from the according controller
        // curently I only set it via the Inspector
        //isPressed = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger);

        // Initially the dist is the maximum pointer distance
        var dist = maxPointerDistance;

        // create the ray from the laserpointer origin
        var ray = new Ray(_holder.position, _holder.forward);

        var hit = new RaycastHit();

        // If using a Collider we have to ignore the Collider of the LaserPointer itself
        if (useCollider)
        {
            var hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, maxPointerDistance);
            hit = hits.FirstOrDefault(h => h.transform != _laser.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxPointerDistance);
        }

        // Are we hitting something?
        if (hit.transform)
        {
            // ignore if still pressing the trigger
            if (!isPressed)
            {
                // Are we hitting something different to what we hit before?
                if (_currentlyHovered && _currentlyHovered != hit.transform)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(_currentlyHovered.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);

                    _currentlyHovered = null;
                }

                // Are we hitting something new?
                if (_currentlyHovered != hit.transform)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(hit.transform.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);

                    _currentlyHovered = hit.transform;
                }
            }

            if (_currentlyHovered == hit.transform)
            {
                // If we are hitting something correct the dist value
                if (hit.distance < maxPointerDistance)
                {
                    dist = hit.distance;
                }

                if (isPressed)
                {
                    HandlePointerDown(hit.transform);
                }
                else
                {
                    HandlePointerUp(hit.transform);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isPressed && _currentlyHovered)
            {
                HandlePointerUp(_currentlyHovered, true);

                ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(_currentlyHovered.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);

                _currentlyHovered = null;
            }
        }

        // Apply changes in the thickness and set the laser dimensions using the dist
        var thickness = !changeThickness || !isPressed ? idleThickness : pressedThickness;
        _laser.transform.localScale = new Vector3(thickness, thickness, dist);
        _laser.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, dist / 2f);

        // Apply color changes
        if (changeColor) _laserMaterial.color = isPressed ? pressedColor : idleColor;

        // Update the pointerEventData
        pointerPosition3D = _laser.transform.position + _laser.transform.forward * dist / 2f;
        pointerPosition2D = _camera.WorldToScreenPoint(pointerPosition3D);
        _pointerEventData.position = pointerPosition2D;
        _pointerEventData.delta = _pointerEventData.position - _lastPointerPosition;
        _lastPointerPosition = _pointerEventData.position;

        _lastPressed = isPressed;
    }

    #endregion MonoBehaviour Messages


    #region Private Methods

    private void HandlePointerDown(Component target)
    {
        if (!target) return;

        // only call once if IsPressed changed its value this frame
        if (_lastPressed != isPressed)
        {
            // Try pointerClickHandler, only use submitHandler as fallback
            // e.g. UI.Button implements both ... would lead to duplicate clicks
            var done = ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
            if (!done) ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.submitHandler);

            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.selectHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.initializePotentialDrag);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!_isDragging)
            {
                // in the first frame use beginDragHandler
                ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
                _isDragging = true;
                _pointerEventData.dragging = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // later use dragHandler
                ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandlePointerUp(Component target, bool forceInvoke = false)
    {
        if (!target) return;

        // only call once if IsPressed changed its value this frame
        // or forceInvoke is set
        if (_lastPressed != isPressed || forceInvoke)
        {
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.deselectHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.endDragHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dropHandler);

            _isDragging = false;
            _pointerEventData.dragging = false;
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

#### VRUIItem.cs

(Based on `VRUIItem.cs` but added the `Update` so dynamic UI like e.g. the `Handles` of the `ScrollBar` in the `ScrollRect` gets its Collider updated)

This has to be placed on basically every UI element that should be interactable for the laser

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class VRUIItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider _boxCollider;
    private RectTransform _rectTransform;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        ValidateCollider();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ValidateCollider();
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        ValidateCollider();
    }

    private void ValidateCollider()
    {
        if (!_rectTransform) _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        if (!_boxCollider) _boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        if (!_boxCollider) _boxCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        _boxCollider.size = _rectTransform.rect.size;
    }
}
```

#### Interactable3D.cs

An example of how you could use the `IPointerXYHandler` interfaces in order to create interactive 3D GameObjects

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Interactable3D : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public Color normalColor;
    public Color hoverColor;

    private Renderer renderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.color = normalColor;
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(" ENTEREd!");
        transform.localScale *= 1.2f;
        renderer.material.color = hoverColor;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("EXIT!");
        transform.localScale /= 1.2f;
        renderer.material.color = normalColor;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("CLICKED!");
    }
}
```

---

#### Demo

As said the scrolling doesn't work quite correct yet, however you can see it is basically possible - maybe just something is wrong about the pointer coordinates I pass in via the `_pointerEventData.position` - **but** all other interactions already work:

[image]