# Unity: Creating a UI for Oculus, how to make a laser pointer and a trigger press activate a button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, oculusquest

I have tried Oculus' UI guide and videos on YT, but nothing has worked. I've used UI Helpers from Oculus' Integration package. It works when I'm in Play mode in the editor, but once I build it, there is no trigger detection and only detects the highlight event. This is my 4th day on this simple UI, it was suppose to take a day!! LOL. 
 *NOTE: I am using Oculus Integration Package instead of Unity's XR system*

[image: UI Button]

Above is the UI Button. I have tried an Event Trigger component and tried using colliders as well.

[image: Laser Pointer]

Above is the Laser Pointer Object provided by UI Helpers from Oculus.

[image]

Above is the Event system provided, trying to make the event be triggered by an Oculus controller trigger. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would this help you [Using Raycast instead of Gaze Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609334/using-raycast-instead-of-gaze-pointer) ?

Comment: Just created a RayCast from my controller to the general forward direction and used a linerenderer to visualize it.